# Interference with cable and electrical in same box

Tags: electrical, low-voltage, coaxial-cable

I'm finishing a basement and am running cable to 2 of the rooms in the basement. I would like to run the cable into a double gang box with the cable outlet on one side and an electrical receptacle on the other. I know that the only way you are supposed to run low voltage to the same box as inline electricity is with a partition in the box for safety. Will this also prevent interference or might that still be an issue? I can put them in separate boxes but was hoping use 1 double gang box as opposed to 2 singles just for aesthetics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are boxes that you can use that has the partition in them to keep the interference down. The trick, possibly for you is to make sure the lines where they run parallel with each other is keeping them separated at a MINIMUM of 6". The low voltage guys I have worked with preferred 12" and more, some wanting 2' separation. If the walls are still open it should not give you no trouble then. When you do pass by a line voltage wire, use an extra foot or two and run the low voltage across the line voltage at a 90 degree angle, this will minimize the "crosstalk" where the cables meet.

Comment: Cat5 is twisted in pairs to reduce the chance of interference.  I have bundled power and Cat5 for 15 years in at least 10 different labs and datacenters and I can count on one finger the issues I have had - and I am not even positive that was interference or a bad cable.  I would simply just test connection with power on.

Comment: The OP mentioned coax cable in the tags, rather than cat5. While it's suggested that cable is shielded, I personally do all I can to maximize separation to minimize the risk of any noise.

Comment: For the 22 years I was a supervisor in high end homes, it was demanded by all our low voltage subs for all wires to separated by some amount. So my company kept it enforced when an employee did not follow through or tried to short cut.  Can only pass on what I know....

Comment: Induction is not your friend, in this case.  ;-)